# Why do Openshift Cron job arbitrarily stop running?

Tags: cron, openshift

I've been running an hourly cron job that worked wonderfully for a little while. One fine day it stopped working. The below are consecutive lines in my cron_hourly.log (note the gap - cron never initiated anything in that time).

```
    Mon Feb  8 18:01:27 EST 2016: END hourly cron run - status=0
__________________________________________________________________________
__________________________________________________________________________ 
    Sun Feb 21 11:01:10 EST 2016: START hourly cron run
__________________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: check what your cron logs think (`/var/log/cron.log`)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the free plan, your gear idles if it has not received any legitimate web traffic within 24 hours.  When your gear is idle, cron jobs do not run.  You can avoid this by upgrading to the Bronze plan.